# c# System.Diagnostics.Process Does Not Do Anything or Throw Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, process

I wonder if someone can please help me understand why my `Process` is not working, nor generating an error.

The code below should loop through a directory, find all files with an `sqb` extension and for each file run a `Process` as a user account which has elevated privileges on the server.

The process should run an executable `sqb2mtf.exe` from the same folder as the files are located with an argument such as `sqb2mtf.exe file.sqb file.bak` for example purposes.

If I use Visual Studio 2013 and step through the code I can see each file being looped through and the `Process` appears to fire, but no files are converted, nor any errors presented to the variable `readToEndError`.

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\inetpub\Import\");

foreach (var file in directory .EnumerateFiles("*.sqb"))
{
    var convert = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.ToString());

    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            FileName = @"D:\inetpub\Import\sqb2mtf.exe",
            UserName = "myUserName",
            Domain = "myDomain",
            Password = GetSecureString("myPassword"),
            Arguments = @"D:\inetpub\Import\" + file + " " + @"D:\inetpub\Import\" + convert + ".bak"
        }
    };
    process.Start();

    string readToEndOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string readToEndError = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    process.WaitForExit();

}
```

I am going out of my mind, any advice to resolve this would be much appreciated :-)

**Update**

```
var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(BackupDirectory);

foreach (var file in directoryInfo.EnumerateFiles("*.sqb"))
{
    var convert = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.ToString());

    var fileName = BackupDirectory + "sqb2mtf.exe";

    var arguments = "\"" + BackupDirectory + file + "\" \"" + BackupDirectory + convert + ".bak\"";

    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = false,
            RedirectStandardError = false,
            FileName = fileName,
            Arguments = arguments
        }
    };
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();

    file.Delete();
}
```

One thing drawing on from the comments by `InBetween` is the need for quotes, in this case the quotes needed to surround the two separate files.

I can confirm this code does work on IISExpress, impersonating the different user, unfortunately just not IIS 7.5.

A workround was to move this code into a Console Application and install on the server in question, then use a Windows Schedule Task to run as a specific account.

Comment: Sanity check: Does it work when you run the command from the `cmd`? `stdout` is empty, too? Does the process return with exit code 0 or something else? If that all checks out good, you must have some issues with `UserName`, `Domain` or `Password` stuff.

Comment: Try set  CreateNoWindow = false so that you can see what happens when the exe runs. It may be throwing an error or message that you can see flash past. Once you have it working then you can hide the window.

Comment: If I set CreateNoWindow to false I get no window appear, if I misspell the username I get an error `Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password` so I would assume rightly or wrongly, that if I don't get this error the domain, username and password are working correctly.

Comment: Is it possible that you need to set the `WorkingDirectory` property?  Some apps require that are run from the folder where they are installed.  Also, the Windows Event log might have some information if an error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some legacy apps, I've discovered that I need to pass the arguments as quoted text, otherwise they simply wouldn't work.

Not sure if this is the issue but it's worth the try:

```
Arguments = "\"D:\\inetpub\\Import\\" + file + " D:\\inetpub\\Import\\" + convert + ".bak\"";
```

Still it seems strange that the process would simply die silently. I'd double check `Domain`, `UserName` and `Password`.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried wrapping the Arguments in quotes, but still no joy. If I misspell the username or password I get an error, but not when all the details are correct.

Comment: I missed the inner quotes, so `var arguments = "\"" + BackupDirectory + file + "\" \"" + BackupDirectory + convert + ".bak\"";` worked, but only on IISExpress.